# curl won't download empty file

Tags: curl

```
curl -o foo.txt http://test.barrycarter.info/emptyfile.txt
curl -O http://test.barrycarter.info/emptyfile.txt
```

I just tried both the above, and neither foo.txt nor emptyfile.txt were created.

How can I make curl create them? Knowing that a file (URL) exists and is empty can be useful.

In particular, I'm trying to mirror geonames daily updates, and it so happens that today's "http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/alternateNamesDeletes-2015-05-28.txt" file is empty. It would be useful to know this instead of simply not downloading it.

(Note: I created an emptyfile above for testing, since geonames' file will disappear within a day)

Comment: You have made 4 errors in the starting word.  The correct spelling is "wget": `wget -O foo.txt http://test.barrycarter.info/emptyfile.txt`  :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Curl didn't use to store anything on zero byte downloads, but it does [since version 7.42.0](http://curl.haxx.se/changes.html#7_42_0).

Answer (score 1):

Can you use `wget` instead? That will do exactly what you want.

If not, try this:

```
curl -v -o file.txt url://... 2> log.txt
grep '^HTTP/.* 404' log.txt
```

The return code from `grep` will be 0 if the file was not found, 1 otherwise.